# Unable to strip the following libraries

Tags: android

Android project build apk ,NDK Unable to strip the following libraries

Task :app:stripReleaseProDebugSymbols

Unable to strip the following libraries, packaging them as they are: libCtaApiLib.so, libShanYCore.so, libgetuiext3.so, libjpegbither.so, liblight.so, libliteavsdk.so, libnbscrash.so, libnbscrash_dumper.so, libndkbitmap.so, librealm-jni.so, librtmp-jni.so, libsecsdk.so, libsophix.so, libsoundtouch.so, libtxffmpeg.so, libtxplayer.so, libtxsdl.so.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: He wants to know what to do with it. I think so

Comment: Is this got fixed ? I am facing same issue after upgrading android studio flamingo